# Где хранится двумерный массив (в стеке или в куче)?

Tags: c++, c

Где хранится двумерный массив (в стеке или в куче)  ?

```cpp
int a[10][10];
```

Comment: https://qr.ae/Te37pU

Comment: Как говори товарищ Бьерне, что закажете - то и будет) статический на стеке, динамический на куче

Comment: Смотря где его объявить. От того, что это массив, ничего не меняется.

Comment: Если такой текст написан внутри функции, то в стеке, если вне функций, то  в bss (статическая область памяти)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Где будет хранится такая переменная зависит от контекста, в котором вы ее объявили. Вы в своем вопросе никакого контекста не привели, по каковой причине и однозначного ответа дать невозможно.

Переменная, объявленная таким способом внутри блока будет автоматической (про такие неформально говорят, что они "хранятся в стеке"). Переменная, объявленная таким способом на уровне файла или пространства имен будет храниться в статической памяти (то, что неформально называют "сегментом данных"). Переменная, объявленная таким способом в классе будет храниться в той памяти, в которой будет хранится сам содержащий эту переменную объект данного класса.

Языки С и С++ не предоставляют способов создания именованных объектов в динамической памяти ("в куче"), т.е. нет способов создать объект "в куче" при помощи вот такого определения, как в вашем примере.

Этот вопрос не имеет никакого особенного отношения ни к многомерным массивам, ни к массивам вообще. Массивы любой размерности в этом отношении ничем не отличаются от переменных любых других типов.

Comment: `нет способов создать объект в куче`. Вы имеете ввиду, что для создания переменной в динамической памяти нужно вызывать `new` или `malloc` или любой другой аллокатор, а все что без этого, это статическая?

Comment: @raviga: Да, именно так "для создания переменной в динамической памяти нужно вызывать new или malloc". Просто определить такую переменную нельзя. Однако без этого переменная совсем не обязательно будет "статической". Термин "статический" не является антонимом термина "динамическая". Откуда лезет такое странное употребление - я не знаю. Например, автоматические массивы не являются статическими.